# HTML for multiple radio groups with the same name

Tags: html, accessibility

What is the most accessible way to split a single radio form (same name) into groups? For example, choosing a time with the groups Today or Tomorrow?

Perhaps split them into two fieldsets?

```
<h3>Select a time and we'll give you a call</h3>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Today</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="a" value="a"/>
    <label for="a">9am</label>

    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="b" value="b"/>
    <label for="b">12pm</label>

    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="c" value="c"/>
    <label for="c">5pm</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Tomorrow</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="d" value="d"/>
    <label for="d">9am</label>

    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="e" value="e"/>
    <label for="e">12pm</label>

    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="f" value="f"/>
    <label for="f">5pm</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: is there any problem with the code you posted?

Comment: nothing wrong with what you posted, maybe just add 'Call Me Today' and 'Call me Tomorrow' as your `legend`s as some people may skip past your `h3` by jumping straight to forms mode, not sure why everyone is trying to offer a solution to a perfectly valid and accessible solution.

Comment: There is even a proposed test (i.e. the way they are expecting people to present information in an ideal world) that proposes that having a fieldset would be a pass and the abscence would be a fail https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test168.html

Comment: Thanks @GrahamRitchie, I haven't seen any examples of multiple fieldsets used like this. Maybe adding screen reader-only content like `<label><span class="visually-hidden">Today at</span> 5pm</label>` could further clarify it.

Comment: Yes you could do it with visually-hidden text if you prefer so as not to change the visual appeal, but other than that your example is perfectly fine. Make sure it says 'Call me' or similar as I am saying that some people may skip your heading so the field should make sense on its own. I am assuming that this is the full form when I say that.

Comment: `<legend><span class="visually-hidden">Call Me </span>Today <span class="visually-hidden">at</span></legend>` could work nicely but I would run it through a screen reader to check it doesn't sound to annoying.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamRitchie, I think that works well. It was redundant adding context to the labels because VoiceOver repeats the legend for each radio. I submitted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach seems to be using multiple fieldsets and in this particular example we want to clarify the legends as [Graham Ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2702894/graham-ritchie) suggested. VoiceOver repeats the legend on each radio so it was redundant to add it to the label as well.

```
<h3>Select a time and we'll give you a call</h3>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><span class="visually-hidden">Call me</span> Today</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="a" value="a"/>
    <label for="a">9am</label>

    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="b" value="b"/>
    <label for="b">12pm</label>

  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><span class="visually-hidden">Call me</span> Tomorrow</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="d" value="d"/>
    <label for="d">9am</label>

    <input type="radio" name="phone" id="e" value="e"/>
    <label for="e">12pm</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the answer.  Not sure you can do this with radio buttons but checkboxes and some javascript should do the trick.

```js
function group1(e){

var id = e.target.id;

var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
   if (boxes[i].id != id)boxes[i].checked=false;
}

}

function group2(e){

var id = e.target.id;

var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(let i=3;i<6;i++){
   if (boxes[i].id != id)boxes[i].checked=false;
}

}
```

```html
<h3>Select a time and we'll give you a call</h3>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Today</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="phone[]" onClick='group1(event)' id="a" value="a"/>
    <label for="a">9am</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="phone[]" onClick='group1(event)' id="b" value="b"/>
    <label for="b">12pm</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="phone[]" onClick='group1(event)' id="c" value="c"/>
    <label for="c">5pm</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Tomorrow</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="phone[]" onClick='group2(event)' id="d" value="d"/>
    <label for="d">9am</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="phone[]" onClick='group2(event)' id="e" value="e"/>
    <label for="e">12pm</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="phone[]" onClick='group2(event)' id="f" value="f"/>
    <label for="f">5pm</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, although I can only allow one selection.